# Server unreachable after ip route del default

Tags: networking, centos7

After i wanted to change default outgoing ip adress with:

```
ip route del default
ip route add default via ipadress
```

my server is unreachable, i have only rescue ssh access.

What i need to do?

Comment: Put the correct route back.

Comment: And how do I do that? I don’t have any expirience with routes and there is really no documentation how to do it from rescue ssh.

Comment: If you have no experience with this, why were you trying to make a change you didn't understand? I would recommend you just reboot it. If you didn't actually change the persistent configuration, then it should get back online with its correct configuration.

Comment: Tried that multiple times, doesnt work, seems that i will need to do full reinstall...

Comment: In that case you probably did make a persistent change that you should not have done. Contact your hosting provider to find the correct IP address and routing information to use.